# How to rescind permission to gather data from an extension publisher in vsc?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Is it on a case by case basis depending which provider? I missclicked on a popup after installing Red Hat's XML extension and accidentally gave them permission. I haven't been able to find any information on it on microsoft's website. Is there a simple way to do it? Or do I have to look through Red Hat's data collection policies? Or is this plain and simple a lost cause? I am not logged into any account on vsc and I have telemetry disabled.